# SQL check if multiple values in group

Tags: sql

I have a product table (1) and a fruit list table (2). I group by product ID and check if any fruit from the fruit table (2) is in the group by from table 1 with this group by statement. How can I check if the group by from table 1 also includes  'potato'.  So results should be PID  1 and 3

table1

```
PID | PRODUCT 
1  | potato 
1  | apple 
1  |  banana
1  | melon
1  | peach 
2  | lime 
2  | apple 
2  | pear 
2  | melon 
3  | pear 
3  | apple 
3  | potato 
3  | mango 
3  | plum
```

table2

```
FID | FRUIT
1 | peach 
2 | lime 
3 | apple 
4 | pear 
5 | apple 
6 | banana
7 | melon
```

```
SELECT PID, COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY PID, PRODUCT 
HAVING  PRODUCT in (SELECT FRUIT FROM table2)
```

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.) ?  SQL is just a language specification, not an actual product.

Comment: The `HAVING` clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one aggregation option.  We can left join the first table to the second, and then assert that both a potato record occur as well as at least one fruit from the second table being present.

```sql
SELECT t1.PID
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.FRUIT = t1.PRODUCT
GROUP BY t1.PID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.PRODUCT = 'potato' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(t2.FRUIT) > 0;
```

Comment: Sorry but my meaning is that the table 1 must be grouped by PID and PRODUCT In each group must have 'potato' and a fruit from the Fruit table (2)

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the feedback, I have updated my answer per your actual requirements.

Comment: SQL Server thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT PID
  FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
    ON PRODUCT = FRUIT OR PRODUCT = 'potato'
 GROUP BY PID
HAVING count(DISTINCT PRODUCT) >= 2 AND array_agg(PRODUCT) @> array['potato']
```

Comment: This answer is fine, assuming the OP is using Postgres.  But do we know this for certain?

Comment: you are absolutely right, this answer is for Postgres, it is not sql standard